# Is there a way to calculate the value of a loot box in game?

Tags: probability, expected-value

I have been playing a game with loot boxes, but these boxes drop items that combine into higher level items, with 3 possibilities of drops.  I need to calculate the average value of each box to determine if it is worth it to purchase loot boxes for profit.  The issue is that each possibility is useable in the final item, but higher level drops require less drops overall.
kind of wordy so i'll see if I can explain
A gem chest can drop one of 3 levels of gems, 1, 2 or 3.  3 level one gems can be upgraded to a level 2 gem, and 3 level 2 gems can be upgraded to a level 3.  To make money, I have to get a level 6 gem (729 level 1, 243 level 2, or 81 level 3 gems), or any combination of the 3 to make a level 6 gem.

Overall, the cost of 1 box is 23 gold, the chance of a level 1 gem is 73%, a level 2 gem is 20%, and a level 3 gem is 7%
it takes 729 level 1 gems to make a level 6 gem, or 243 level 2 gems to make a level 6 gem, or 81 level 3 gems to make a level 6 gem, and a level 6 gem sells for 6000 gold

Is there any way to calculate something like this?  Where there are 3 variables, and every result is used to move closer to the desired result?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I was way over thinking, and was able to determine a workable average, will post my solution here in case anyone notices something I did wrong, or wants to do the same thing elsewhere and was having the same problems I was.

L1 = 729
L2 = 243
L3 = 81

Cost of box: 23G

Odds of L1=73%
Odds of L2=20%
Odds of L3=7%

Cost if all L1 = 16767
Cost if all L2 =  5589
Cost if all L3 =  1863

Final Value of combinations: 6000
100 box pulls:
73 T1 gems
20 T2 Gems
7  T3 Gems

73 T1=24 T2
24+20=44 T2
44 T2=14 T3

Average of 21 L3 gems in 100 boxes
Average of 385 boxes to return a level 6 gem
average cost of 8855 gold to return 6000 gold

Not Worth buying boxes